# How to run typedoc for Angular CLI

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, angular-cli, typedoc

When I run the following command:

```
typedoc --out ./docs --mode file --target ES6 ./src/
```

it gives the following results:

> ```
> Using TypeScript 3.7.4 from /usr/lib/node_modules/typedoc/node_modules/typescript/lib
> Error: /home/ersincebi/Masaüstü/projects/ANGULAR/whentheringbells/node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(72)
>  Duplicate identifier 'IteratorResult'.
> Error: /home/ersincebi/Masaüstü/projects/ANGULAR/whentheringbells/src/app/services/course/course-service.service.ts(15)
>  Spread types may only be created from object types.
> Error: /home/ersincebi/Masaüstü/projects/ANGULAR/whentheringbells/src/app/services/course/course-service.service.ts(36)
> Error: /usr/lib/node_modules/typedoc/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.iterable.d.ts(40)
>  Duplicate identifier 'IteratorResult'.
> ```

I tried to upgrade npm, typescript, and angular to latest version but it still gives the same result.

Comment: hi and welcome, what about to share the code of the source file with error ? `core-service`.
A bit off-topic but for Angular projects I'd suggest [compodoc](https://compodoc.app/) instead of typedoc

Comment: I'll try this now.